# Kubernetes Pod Keeps Restarting (CrashBackoffLoop - Error: Request Time Out)

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I am somewhat brand-new to Kubernetes.

I have a pod that keeps restarting, and my error is:

```
    at KibanaTransport.request (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:524:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at KibanaTransport.request (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/core-elasticsearch-client-server-internal/target_node/create_transport.js:58:16)
    at Cluster.getSettings (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/cluster.js:157:16)
    at isInlineScriptingEnabled (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/core-elasticsearch-server-internal/target_node/is_scripting_enabled.js:22:20)
    at ElasticsearchService.start (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/core-elasticsearch-server-internal/target_node/elasticsearch_service.js:128:32)
    at Server.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/server.js:366:32)
    at Root.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/root/index.js:69:14)
    at bootstrap (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/bootstrap.js:120:5)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/src/cli/serve/serve.js:216:5)
[2023-08-19T12:01:21.293+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Stopping all plugins.
[2023-08-19T12:01:21.294+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.standard] Stopping all plugins.
[2023-08-19T12:01:21.294+00:00][INFO ][plugins.monitoring.monitoring.kibana-monitoring] Monitoring stats collection is stopped
[2023-08-19T12:01:21.297+00:00][ERROR][plugins.ruleRegistry] Error: Server is stopping; must stop all async operations
    at /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/rule_registry/server/rule_data_plugin_service/resource_installer.js:66:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2023-08-19T12:01:21.298+00:00][ERROR][plugins.ruleRegistry] Error: Failure installing common resources shared between all indices. Server is stopping; must stop all async operations
    at ResourceInstaller.installWithTimeout (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/rule_registry/server/rule_data_plugin_service/resource_installer.js:75:13)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at ResourceInstaller.installCommonResources (/usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/rule_registry/server/rule_data_plugin_service/resource_installer.js:89:5)

 FATAL  TimeoutError: Request timed out
```

The rest of my pods are running:

[image]

`kubectl describe pod`

[image]
What I've Tried:
Deleted the pod on its own.
Removed the deployment.
Updated the YAML file to allocate more resources and applied the changes. However, I'm uncertain if the changes were actually applied.

If anyone is a Kubernetes expert, I would be very appreciative if someone could provide proper guidance here.

Thank you.

Comment: Just the error message and some diagnostics aren't really enough to diagnose the issue.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Include the text of command outputs rather than screen shots of terminal windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to do remote diagnostics with that amount of information. Here are basically two things that disturb me. Your Kubernetes pod running Kibana is encountering issues and keeps restarting due to errors related to communication with Elasticsearch.

**1:** The "Readiness probe failed: Get https://xxxxx.login dial tcp connect connection refused" message suggests that Kibana is failing its readiness probe. A readiness probe is used to determine if a container is ready to start accepting traffic.

- Verify that the readiness probe configuration for the Kibana pod is
  correct. It might be misconfigured or the service it's trying to
  access ("login" in this case) might not be ready or available.
- Check the service name, port, and path used in the readiness probe. Ensure they match the actual configuration of the application.
- increase the timeout of the readiness probe

**2:** The error message "TimeoutError: Request timed out" indicates that there's an issue with Kibana's communication with Elasticsearch.

- Check if the Elasticsearch service is up and running and accessible from the Kibana pod.
- Ensure that the Elasticsearch URL and credentials are correctly configured in the Kibana configuration.
- Verify that there are no network policies or firewalls blocking communication between Kibana and Elasticsearch.
- Check resource allocation for both Kibana and Elasticsearch pods. Ensure they have enough resources (CPU, memory) allocated to perform their tasks.